# Sort and array maintaining index value

Tags: perl

1. I stored some values in the array as follows $score[$userIndex] = :

`Score [100, 400, 900]`

`userIndex (1  , 2  ,  3 )`

I need to ascending numeric sort based on the score while maintaining the indexes, as they have significance, the result should resemble:

```
    Score [100, 400, 900]
userIndex (2  , 1  ,  3 )
```

2. After the sort is complete how can I access the previous index an element was at(after the sort is complete I no longer need the score just the indexes)?
In the sorted array all i need is for eg: `$sorted[0] = 2, $sorted[1] = 1, $sorted[3] = 3`

Comment: I don't really understand what you're doing, but: sort into a new array? Then you have the old and the new array available...

Comment: @TedBear I need to sort based on the score into a new array based on the 'Score' field of the first array. After sort i all need is the index that 'Score' had in the first array. The array i want to end up with is essentially [2, 1, 3] due to the 'Score' that was at theses indexes in the 1st array

Comment: I think you mean your `@score` array to be `(400, 100, 900)`. It is already sorted as you have it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this method of doing it after some extensive googling

```
while ($hashIndex < $#Score) {
    $matchHash{$hashIndex} = $Score[$hashIndex];
    $hashIndex++;
} 

foreach my $score (sort { $matchHash{$a} <=> $matchHash{$b} } keys %matchHash) {
    #DS
        # printf "%-8s %s\n", $score, $matchHash{$score};
    push (@sorted, $score);

}
```

Comment: You are effectively copying the array information to a hash, which is a bad idea for two reasons. Firstly, hashes are intended to be indexed by strings and not by numbers, secondly there is no point in duplicating the information - your `sort` call can just as easily use the `@Score` array directly.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to sort a list of *array indices* instead of the data itself. Then you can reorder the corresponding list of users using the same sorted indices.

The code would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @score = (400, 100, 900);
my @users = (1, 2, 3);

my @sorted_indices = sort { $score[$a] <=> $score[$b] } 0 .. $#score;

my @sorted_users = @users[@sorted_indices];

print "@sorted_users\n";
```

**output**

```
2 1 3
```

**Update**

Looking at your own code, it looks like perhaps all you want is the sorted array indices, (i.e. the `userIndex` list in your question should properly be `(0, 1, 2)`). If that is the case the the sort is complete when `@sorted_indices` is filled.

```
print "@sorted_indices\n";
```

outputs

```
1 0 2
```